# Laravel: Call a factory inside another factory

Tags: laravel-8

I want to seed my database using laravel 8 factories. I have a shop and each can have several campaign active.

So in my shop model i define the relation:

```
public function campaigns() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ShopCampaign','id_shop', 'ID');
}
```

as well in the campaign models it's defined the inverse relation

```
public function shop() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Shop','id_shop', 'ID');
}
```

then i define the campaign factory:

```
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\ShopCampaign;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class ShopCampaignFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = ShopCampaign::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        $date_ins = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-1 week', '-2 days')->getTimeStamp());
        $starts_at = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_ins)->addDays( $this->faker->numberBetween( 2, 5 ) );
        $ends_at= Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $starts_at)->addDays( $this->faker->numberBetween( 20, 30 ) );
        
        $attributes = [
            'datestart' => $starts_at,
            'dateend' => $ends_at,
            'name' => 'Test',
            'dateins' => $date_ins
        ];

        return $attributes;
    }

}
```

Now the result i want to achieve is to create 5 shops and each of them have to have 3 active campaigns. This means than when creating the campaign the `id_shop` must be populated. But what i think it's the id shoul magically be taken by the defined relations. But if I make a seed class and call:

```
Shop::factory(5)->has(ShopCampaign::factory()->count(3), 'campaigns')->create();
```

I got:

```
 Call to undefined method App\Models\ShopCampaign::factory()
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've just discovered the answer, it's not written clearly in the manual. In the ShopCampaign manual you have to add:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class ShopCampaign extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    [...]
}
```

Comment: Hi, for future reference here is the guide to creating Laravel factories which references using the HasFactory trait - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#creating-models-using-factories